#  LogCATError while starting new activities

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-intent

My problem is in starting new activities.
I have `ListView`, items of it are defined from string-array by this code:

```
listBanksUA = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_banks_ua);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listBanksUA));
```

List is defined in layout as:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
```

So, I'd like to start new activity after click on item of `ListView`. Sure, I have created new XML-layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<ListView
android:id="@+id/listRegions"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>  

</LinearLayout>
```

and Java-class for it: `ListRegionsActivity.class`.
In my first `Activity` I use the follow code to start new `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListRegionsActivity.class));
    }
```

and after clicking in started application I'm getting an error, that my application has been closed with advice to try again. Sadness...

So, really I'll be glad for any help for me.
BTW: of course, I added new activity to manifest file.

UPD: my LogCAT with Error flag

```
08-15 13:46:45.458: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ua.donetsk.jeston.android/ua.donetsk.jeston.android.ListRegionsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:236)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1620)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at ua.donetsk.jeston.android.ListRegionsActivity.onCreate(ListRegionsActivity.java:15)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
08-15 13:46:45.488: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(516):     ... 11 more
```

UPD: the problem is solved. The reason was in incorrect mistake in opening avtivity - setContentView should be deleted.

Comment: What error is in your Logcat?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not showed us the LogCat trace, I can do the guess.

Try this in the `ListView` click listener

`MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListRegionsActivity.class))`

And dont forget to add the new activity in your manifest.

Comment: Unfortunally, it does't work - I see same error. But I've added LogCat  with Error flag. Please, glance on it.

Comment: Ohhh, due to you - I've checked te log and defined the reason of the error. Due to you - becouse of eчфседн your comment caused my to learn what's LogCAT. Thanks!))

Answer (score 0):

Check you're not importing android.R in your app instead of your.package.R